# Pass arguments through Main(string[] args) in VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, program-entry-point

How do i pass arguments to through Main(string[] args) when I am trying to run multiple projects through Visual Studio.

I normally right click on the project and select: Debug -> Start new instance. At this point how do I pass arguments?

Comment: You need to execute the .exe within a command line. Like this: Application.exe argument1 argument2

Comment: Then how do I still debug?

Comment: Do you mean multiple projects (in which case see Patrick's answer) or do you mean multiple instances of the same executable?

Comment: @Sanja Malpani Wasn't aware that you needed to debug it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are running with a debugger, you can change the way the application is called through the Project Settings.

Open `Project Settings` > `Debug`, and set `Command Line Arguments`.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Right click the project, select Properties. Under the Debug tab, you can pass in command line arguments

Answer (score 1):

Here one Console App example

```
using System;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++) // Loop through array
        {
            Console.WriteLine(args[i]);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

> "C:\ConsoleApp1.exe" a b c

**OUTPUT**:

```
a
b
c
```